# Mongo lookup querying is failed from a collection consists of ~1.2 million records

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

There are 2 collections: **Alerts** & **AlertTypes**.
The **Alerts** collection have a field called: alertTypeId which is the lookup/foreign key of the **AlertTypes** collection.

I need to optimize the following query where I fetch the data from the **Alerts** collection along with the AlertType Name by joining the corresponding collection.

I used the aggregate function as follows:

```
db.Alerts.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "status": {
            "$ne": -1
        },
        "type": 4
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "localField": "alertTypeId",
        "from": "AlertTypes",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "alertTypeRel"
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "alertTypeId": 1,
        "alertTypeRel.alertTypeName": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "message": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "startDate": 1,
        "createdAt": 1,
        "createdBy": 1,
        "validUntil": 1,
        "errorFlag": 1,
        "extApiId": 1,
        "errorMessage": 1,
        "autoPublish": 1,
        "statusChangedBy": 1
    }
},{
    "$sort": {
        "status": 1,
        "createdAt": -1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        },
        "results": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "total": "$count",
        "_id": 0,
        "results": {
            "$slice": ["$results", 0, 10]
        }
    }
}], {
    "collation": {
        "locale": "en",
        "strength": 2
    },
    "allowDiskUse": true,
    "cursor": {}
}).pretty();
```

I have indexed the fields as well. for egs:

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "status" : 1,
            "createdAt" : -1
        },
        "name" : "status_1_createdAt_-1"
}
```

There are 1 250 543 & 117 records in the **Alerts** & **AlertTypes** collections respectively. I tried the `facet` query as well, but that also throwing the same following result:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes",
    "code" : 146,
    "codeName" : "ExceededMemoryLimit"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:639:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:729:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1058:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Thanks

Comment: Term "lak" is not really known outside of India.

Answer (score 1):

The `$group` stage is using too much memory while push `$$ROOT` object, There are few fixes, Simply use `$facet` instead of `$group` and `$project` stages,

- for pagination you can use `$skip` and `$limit` stages,
- for count total documents use `$count` operator
- `$facet` to separate both `result` and `count`
- use `$lookup` after `$limit` stage because we are fetching 10 documents and only required to lookup only 10 documents
- use `$project` after lookup if needed

You final query would be,

```
db.Alerts.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": { "$ne": -1 },
      "type": 4
    }
  },    
  {
    "$sort": {
      "status": 1,
      "createdAt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      result: [
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 10 },
        {
          "$lookup": {
           "localField": "alertTypeId",
           "from": "AlertTypes",
           "foreignField": "_id",
           "as": "alertTypeRel"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "title": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "alertTypeId": 1,
            "alertTypeRel.alertTypeName": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "message": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "startDate": 1,
            "createdAt": 1,
            "createdBy": 1,
            "validUntil": 1,
            "errorFlag": 1,
            "extApiId": 1,
            "errorMessage": 1,
            "autoPublish": 1,
            "statusChangedBy": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      count: [{ $count: "total" }]
    }
  } 
], 
{
  "collation": {
    "locale": "en",
    "strength": 2
  },
  "allowDiskUse": true,
  "cursor": {}
})
.pretty();
```

- For more performance you can use indexing on matching condition field and sorting fields, as per your query use can use compound index on `status`, `type` and `createdAt` see more details about [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

> This query is not tested!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the above query took more than 5 mins. Also, we can't sort the data before the lookup because sometimes, the sorting will be based on the alert type name in the lookup collection that depends upon the sort request parameter coming in the API.

Comment: can you add explain state of this query, using `.explain('executionStats')` see [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation)

Comment: Explain stats added in the below link. Please have a look,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4edrw77ugtc28cd/Document.docx?dl=0

Comment: I am not sure why its both rejecting and wining the index, this is just explain state can you add `.explain('executionStats')` it will show which stage taking too much execution time, and can you ask this question and with explain state in [mongodb forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/) you will get exact and detailed solution.

Comment: Sure, FYI I am using mongo 4.4.1, I think there is a syntax difference for this explain(). I will check and update that steps here.

Comment: Mongo tells the syntax: db.Alerts.explain().aggregate..... for the explain() in mongo in 4.4.1. The same output I have provided above. Do you think there is another query has to be executed?

Comment: can you try `db.Alerts.explain("executionStats").aggregate..` this, have you asked your question in mongodb forum?

Comment: Thanks. Included the stats here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd67vj1ayfx2vau/Mongo-explain-stats.docx?dl=0. Please have a look

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this?

Comment: 1) I think you have to create a index for your search fields `{ status: 1, type: 1 }`, after adding index try performance, 2) the collection language and strength `"collation": {"locale": "en","strength": 2 },` taking more time, just try removing and check difference of response, if its not required then don't use 3) try removing $project stage if not needed because it will improve 10%-20% of performance.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but no difference. But let me tell you one thing, I just removed all complex stages like, lookup, project, sort etc and used only the aggregate match and group from the Alerts collection. Sttll it takes too much time to complete. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you check this image: This itself took a few minutes to complete
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9eu6xvxvzdfyg02/mongo-aggregate.png?dl=0

Comment: I am not sure, i think you have to ask to mongodb forum that i have referred in previous comment.

Comment: I have asked there already.
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-lookup-querying-is-failed-from-a-collection-consists-of-12-lak-records/100986